# camunda in docker

Tags: docker, camunda

Запустил стандартный контейнер из докер-хаба. Получил ошибку:

> WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested"

Запустить под маком невозможно? Чип M1.

Команда:

```
docker pull camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:latest
```

Детали смотрел [тут](https://hub.docker.com/r/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/). Документация по [camunda7](https://docs.camunda.org/get-started/)

Comment: Люди запускают: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67458621/how-to-run-amd64-docker-images-on-arm64-host-platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне помогло:

```
docker run --rm -ti --platform linux/amd64 -p 8080:8080 camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:7.16.0
```

Но, вероятно, это не будет работать для camunda8. Не факт, что это поможет вам. Попробуйте один из других способов, если этот не подошёл. Судя по всему, есть несколько решений вопроса:

- Собрать свой контейнер под ARM из [исходников](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform) camunda7. Взять alpine linux под arm, туда джаву под арм, туда камунду со спрингбутом
- Использовать транслятор [Rosetta](https://support.apple.com/ru-ru/HT211861), но может тормозить. [Дополнительно](https://www.rosetta-api.org/docs/node_deployment.html) для докера
- Сделать мульти-архитектурный контейнер. Детали можно уточнить в [чате](https://t.me/camunda_bpm/34307)
- Запустить докер-контейнер на виртуальной машине и попробовать работать там, если вам нужно протестировать решение
- Запускать образ `camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:7.16.0`
- Спросить помощь в [чате](https://t.me/camunda_bpm), в телеграмм под вашу проблему
- [Поискать](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/issues) ответы в github issues
- Собрать свой докер-файл под архитектуру: "[specify the platform in the FROM command just put this at the top](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71442984)"
- [Разобраться](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69054921/docker-on-mac-m1-gives-the-requested-images-platform-linux-amd64-does-not-m), как запускать контейнеры под определённую платформу